# How do you decode the Flag attribute on the List element?

Tags: list, list-definition

How to decode the `Flags` attribute of a SharePoint List? What does `4104` mean?

```
    <List DocTemplateUrl="/SiteAssets/Forms/template.doc"
DefaultViewUrl="/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx" ... 
WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="4104" ... other properties/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation does not mention this attribute at all, either [for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx) or [for WSS 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091%28v=office.12%29.aspx). This and its generic name suggests that `Flags` is "for internal use only".

From experience discussing such things with Microsoft Support in the past, that means use of this attribute by end users is not supported. If you are creating your own list definition then **don't specify it**. If you have extracted a list definition from an existing SharePoint site that contains `Flags` then **ignore or remove it**.